# Marketing Cloud - Change Poll Frequency for Synchronized Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a hourly sync between our salesforce and our marketing cloud.

Ideally we would want this sync to happen only once a day.

But we are not able to find any option for that as shown below

[image]

The poll schedule is either 15 minutes, 30 minutes or 1 hour.

Is it not possible then to have this polling done only once per day ?

We have about 10k contacts in SF. During the synch process, I assume the existing contacts from MC will be purged and repopulated from SF. If this process happens once a day, then we wont have issues. But if this "purging/repopulating" happens every hour, then i assume it will cause issues while when a journey/send is being prepared by our marketing users.

Comment: Why would you want to reduce it to once a day?

Comment: Thanks. @LukasLunow I updated the post with the reason for low polling frequency.

Comment: _During the synch process, I assume the existing contacts from MC will be purged and repopulated from SF_ : what led you to this assumption?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. Contacts will only be removed from MC if they don't fit the sync criteria (if any are configured in your MCC settings).

Comment: @identigral thanks for pointing it out...I noticed that when existing contacts do not meet the entry criteria anymore they were removed from the synchronized data extension ...thats why i assumed it that the synching process must be purging/repopulating